# how do I basic script with linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

what does this command do?

```
!/bin/bash
```

My first script

```
clear
echo (I don't know what will come after echo , can you help me with that too?)
./hello.shell
```

Comment: I don't think this is the place to ask for someone to tech you shell scripting.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the code , it is not supposed to be like this. And I have exam tomorrow in linux scripting , just the basics. Can you help me find help? Please , thanks.

Comment: Have you considered reading a book?

Comment: I don't have a book about scripting with bash shell. Is there a book online?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the down votes are b/c you can search the web for tutorials.  You don't need personal responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!/bin/bash` is called the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))  (you missed the leading `#`).
It tells which program will execute your script.

`clear` is for clearing screen.

`echo` outputs following argument to the standard output (your terminal by default). But you must not surround your string with parenthesis as it's used for grouping command in a sub-shell. If you want to print `(...)`, you'll have too use double quotes :

```
echo "(I don't know what will come after echo , can you help me with that too?)"
```

`./hello.shell` will execute your script after you gave it execute permissions with `chmod +x hello.shell`.

Note that commonly used extension for a shell script is `.sh` rather than `.shell`.

For more, try theses links :

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/

Comment: Thanks Kenavoz , that really helped me a lot !

Comment: Pointing at the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/) is probably better than that guide (assuming that guide is written like their ABS which is very poorly written).

Comment: @EtanReisner Added the link.

Comment: There is no particular need for the shell script to have any extension at all. Just call it `hello`

Answer (score 0):

`#!/bin/bash` tells to the SO that this file is a script and that bash is the shell that must execute it. So you can found: `#!/opt/bin/perl` for perl scripts, `#!/bin/csh` for c-shell, `#!/bin/zsh` ...