# Execute commands in specific location and depending on answer of previous command

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently working on a Text-to-speech project and I need to write bash script which will, when it is called, execute two commands. If the first command returns the proper answer (if returns an answer at all), the second command will be called and executed.

My question is, how can I write a script, that executes shell commands in a specific certain file system location?

For example, I need to be in the directory `/opt/text/example` and execute this command:

```
sudo ./bin/sample_read -I ../languages/ -I ../languages -v dave -T 2 \
    -i /opt/text/example.txt -F 22 -O embedded-pro -o out_file.pcm
```

and then to wait for the answer, then (if it is good) execute the second command.

The second command is

```
aplay -f S16_LE -r 22050 -c 1 out_file.pcm
```

Comment: How exactly is the "good answer" defined? Is it the exit status of the first command? Does it print something to standard output?

Comment: What do you mean by "wait for the answer"? Do you have a two-way human-computer dialog with a microphone input, or do you expect the user (or an operator) to press a key, or do you simply mean wait for the first command to finish?

Comment: Perhaps the only answer you need is that the things you can type on the command line can be put in a file which can then be executed by the shell. There are a few motions which are impossible to guess if you haven't done this before but look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604296/how-do-i-basic-script-with-linux

Comment: @benjamin W. when the first command is executed, it will generate speach file and it will print in terminal that the process is endded.

Comment: @tripleee i have a button on my board that user presses when he wants to generate and listen to audio file on speakers,we need to wait until generating audio file is done...and then second command is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
pushd /path/to/directory
my_var=$(command1)
if [ "$my_var" == "expected_result" ]; then
  command2
fi
popd
```

You basically run command1 and store its output in `my_var`. Then you compare the content of `$my_var` with whatever you're expecting.

Also `pushd <path>`/`popd` allow you to move to a directory and back.

Comment: My *nix is very rusty, generally from 1980's, but shouldn't there be backquotes?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf , No, not required. either you can do it as ` `command` ` or $(command)

Comment: `$()` is preferred over backticks due to simpler nesting, I wouldn't have changed it. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: @BenjaminW. you're right, reverted back my answer to `$()`